# Add image to post

Tags: plugins, images

I've tried attach an image to post but my code doesn't work and I tried a lot of things, a lot of code, etc. What happen? I've tried with this:

```
            $postData = array(
              'post_title'    => 'My post',
              'post_content'  => '',
              'post_status'   => 'publish',
              'post_author'   => 1,
              'post_category' => array( 8,39 )
            );
            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $postData );

            $getImageFile = '/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/pluginQ/test.jpg';

            $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            $image_data = file_get_contents($getImageFile);
            $filename = basename($getImageFile);
            if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path'])){
              $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
            }
            else{
              $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
            }                                   
            file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

            $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
            $attachment = array(
                'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status' => 'inherit'
            );
            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );
            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
            $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
            set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same problem about 4 5 days , until I found this code , try some tweaks and see if works :)

```
#Upload and Create attachment
        if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
        }
            $upload = wp_upload_bits( $_FILES['file']['name'], null, file_get_contents( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ) );
            $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $upload['file'] ), null );
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
            if($check !== false) {
            $uploadOk = 1;
                } else {
                echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
                wp_trash_post( $post_id  );
            }

            $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            $attachment = array(
                'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['baseurl'] . _wp_relative_upload_path( $upload['file'] ),
                'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $upload['file'] )),    
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_author' => $user_id,
                'post_status' => 'inherit'
            );
            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload['file'], $post_id );
            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
            $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $upload['file'] );
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    #Upload and Create attachment

    #Use attachment
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id );
    #Use attachment
```